# upload video in facebook and twitter in ios

Tags: ios, facebook, twitter

Now currently I m creating an video app for iphone. I m new to ios. In my app I need to share my video in Facebook as well as Twitter. I dont know how to done this. Then my app should support IOS5, IOS6 and IOS7. So I need any method to support all these versions.. Any suggestion greatly appreceated..

Comment: Have you looked to the facebook and twitter apis for answering your quetion? Also there is built-in support (ios 6 and above) for twitter and facebook. Take a look at the Social.framework.

Comment: @NikosM.:You look at my question I need that from IOS5

Comment: As I mentioned, take a look at twitter and facebook sdks for ios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first hit on Google to "facebook video ios" points to a tutorial on uploading videos to Facebook: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2011/08/04/how-to--use-the-graph-api-to-upload-a-video--ios/

More details on the video Graph API: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/video/

I think you can do the same search query for uploading videos to Twitter.

Comment: :Above link facebook sdk lot of files missing are you having that adk means please upload for me

Comment: :Hi thanks great it was work for me....But how can I done this for Twitter